# maven sql plugin 0 of 0 SQL statements executed successfully

Tags: maven

What i want is to be able to create/drop db from maven (if it is possible). I've found maven sql plugin but can't understand how to, for example, create db. Somehow maven says me that no sql commands. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Here is the result

```
    d:\Projects\Learn\hibernate>mvn sql:execute
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building App 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (default-cli) @ learn ---
[INFO] 0 of 0 SQL statements executed successfully
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.027s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 18 11:34:25 MSK 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/107M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>learn-hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>learn</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>App</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.build.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>App.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <!-- specify the dependent jdbc driver here -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <configuration>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432</url>
                    <username>postgres</username>
                    <password>123456</password>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>jdbc:postgressql://localhost:5432</url>
                            <!-- no transaction -->
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <sqlCommand>create database "hib"</sqlCommand>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo in one of your URLs, `postgressql` must be `postgresql`.

When you run `mvn sql:execute` it is only picking up the plugin configuration, not a plugin execution, unless you give it the `id` `default-cli` (yours had just `default`).

The plugin execution that you had configured may have worked when running a normal lifecycle such as `mvn compile` or `mvn install` (as opposed to `mvn sql:execute`), however, for that to work you need a `plugins.plugin` definition (as opposed to a `pluginManagement.plugins.plugin` definition.

You can in fact `CREATE` and `DROP` databases using this plugin. I've done it and used it extensively for unit testing. We had four stages:

1. Create database. Executed from the generic database
2. Run DDL. Executed from the newly created database
3. Run unit test
4. Drop database. Executed from the generic database

If the unit test fails your database does not get dropped, which may be a good thing for analysis. This does mean that creating the database has to deal with the to-be-created database already being there (`onError=continue`).

Comment: Especially the third paragraph explains why you got `0 of 0 SQL statements executed successfully`. You've configured the sqlCommand as part of an execution-block, not as general configuration, so `sql:exec` won't work.

Comment: I think you really need both the second *and* the third paragraph to fix it.

Comment: d'oh... what a newbie mistake. I'm ashamed. Fixing typo helped. Thanks.